# correct pattern for reducer to handle messages

Tags: redux, react-redux

So i have a dialog component, that can fill many tasks, and dispatch actions 
"SUBMIT_X", "SUBMIT_Y" etc...

Dialog is being toggled on "SHOW_DIALOG" and "HIDE_DIALOG" action types,
Question is, should the `isDialogVisible` reducer will look like this?

```
const isDialogVisible = (state = false, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case "SHOW_DIALOG" :
            return true;
        case "HIDE_DIALOG" :
        case "SUBMIT_X" :
        case "SUBMIT_Y" :
            return false;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Or should i dispatch "HIDE_DIALOG" whenever i dispatch "SUBMIT_X", "SUBMIT_Y"?
Issues with approach 1 : 
i need to handle actions from `actions/X.js` and `actions/Y.js` inside `reducers/dialog.js` which can arise maintenance and scalabilities issues
Issues with approach 2 : 
over dispatching... and therefore causing unnecessary re-renders.

Comment: I do not understand why dispatching two different actions causes unnecessary re-renders. If the action you dispatch do not change the props passed to your dialog, there should not be any re-render.

Comment: well from my understanding, every dispatch "re-render"` the state tree, and on every re-render, all containers components are calling their `mapDispatchToProps` - this is not necessarily a presentational react component re-render.

Comment: That's true, you understand it correctly. IMO, as long as there is no real re-render of the DOM you need not worry too much about it. In fact, there is one thing you can do to gain better performance. That is to use memoized selectors inside `mapDispatchToProps`. Have a look at this http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html

Comment: yeah i am already using reselect, whats worrying me is just the correct pattern and best practices, and since i am quite new to redux, i am not sure, and just learning. from 1ven and Khang comments, i understood that approach 2 is the way, but from this [link](https://tech.affirm.com/redux-patterns-and-anti-patterns-7d80ef3d53bc#82c8), i understand that approach 1 is the way.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is small enough 1st approach can work, but it's not scalable.

In my opinion 2nd approach is more preferable, as from architectural perspective `dialog` reducer should not be aware of any other unrelated actions.

For 2nd approach, to listen actions, you can use libraries like `redux-saga` or `redux-observable`.

I'm not performance expert, but I believe, that on the first place we should care about maintainability and only after about performance. Furthermore in that situation possible unnecessary re-renders is not a big deal.